# resque-pool defaulting to test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, resque

I set up resque-pool locally today and I have noticed some strange behaviour. I had previously got plain old resque up and running no problem. My jobs were failing because records could not be found. When I dug into this I found that this is because the workers are being set up with the test configuration. I'm using foreman/heroku local and my .env file sets the environment`RACK_ENV=development`, I also tried added a `RACK_ENV=development`

Sample set up output

```
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
5:01:34 PM web.1    |  Puma starting in single mode...
5:01:34 PM web.1    |  * Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
5:01:34 PM web.1    |  * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
5:01:34 PM web.1    |  * Environment: development
5:01:34 PM worker.1 |  resque-pool-manager[curio-api][1751]: Resque Pool running in development environment
5:01:36 PM web.1    |  * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
5:01:36 PM web.1    |  Use Ctrl-C to stop
5:01:36 PM worker.1 |  resque-pool-manager[curio-api][1751]: started manager
```

My tasks/resque.rake file

```
require 'resque/pool/tasks'

# this task will get called before resque:pool:setup
# and preload the rails environment in the pool manager
task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  # generic worker setup, e.g. Hoptoad for failed jobs
end

task "resque:pool:setup" => :environment do
  # close any sockets or files in pool manager
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  # and re-open them in the resque worker parent
  Resque::Pool.after_prefork do |job|
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end
```

I'm not sure why the environment variables aren't being picked. I'm also a little surprised that resque-pool is defaulting to test. I'm using 0.6.0 in a rails 5.0 api only app. I'm sure I must be doing something silly but  I can't see what it it

Just in case it helps, messing around with byebug

```
✗ resque-pool

[7, 16] in /Users/conornugent/Dev/neighbourwood/curio/curio-api/lib/tasks/resque.rake
    7: end
    8:
    9: task "resque:pool:setup" => :environment do
   10:   # close any sockets or files in pool manager
   11:   byebug
=> 12:   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
   13:   # and re-open them in the resque worker parent
   14:   Resque::Pool.after_prefork do |job|
   15:     ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
   16:   end
(byebug) Rails.env
"test"
(byebug) ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database
"curio-api_test"
```

I posted an issue about this but I'm guessing this could be down to something I'm doing so this might be the more appropriate home for my query

https://github.com/nevans/resque-pool/issues/158

Answer (score 1):

I never really got to the bottom of why `bundle exec resque-pool` was defaulting to 'test'(somehow the Rails.env was returning test)  but switching my Profile from

```
worker: bundle exec resque-pool
```

to the following

```
worker: bundle exec rake resque:pool
```

ensured the environment was set properly. If anyone has any ideas about why `bundle exec resque-pool` was acting so strangely please let me know